# Get list of friends n depth

Tags: mysql, sql

I have simple table friends that look like that:

[image]

With the id of a person (id_friend) and the id of its friend (id_friend_of).

I'm trying to get all the IDs of friends of a specific user with a depth, so get all people linked to a specific user with a determined depth.

What I'm trying for a depth of 2 (get the friends of the user and the friends of its friends) :

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    a.id_friend_of
FROM friend a
JOIN friend b
    ON b.id_friend = a.id_friend_of
WHERE a.id_friend = 1 AND
      b.id_friend <> a.id_friend
```

But it's not working, I'm only getting the friends of the user but not the friends of friends.
What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Add desired output for shown source data.

Comment: I just want a list of ids

Comment: Show **desired** list of IDs which you need to obtain for shown source data **strictly**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> get the friends of the user and the friends of its friends

You can get the friends of the user with a simple filtered query on the table and the friends of friends with a self join of the table.
Then use `UNION` to get the results of the 2 queries, which will also remove duplicates:

```
SELECT id_friend_of
FROM friend
WHERE id_friend = 1
UNION
SELECT f2.id_friend_of
FROM friend f1 INNER JOIN friend f2
ON f2.id_friend = f1.id_friend_of
WHERE f1.id_friend = 1 AND f2.id_friend_of <> 1
```

For levels above 2, it's better to use a recursive query (for MySql 8.0+):

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT *, 1 level 
  FROM friend
  WHERE id_friend = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT f.*, level + 1
  FROM cte c INNER JOIN friend f
  ON f.id_friend = c.id_friend_of
  WHERE f.id_friend_of <> 1 AND level < 2 -- for level = 2
)
SELECT DISTINCT id_friend_of
FROM cte
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fa580e95102ea8f91f2edad2ba7a6637).

Comment: Do you have any example for the recursive query ? I'm using MySQL 8.0.21

Comment: @Jessy it is there in my answer.